# Can I, underage, get a US passport with consent from both parents, but without either present?

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens

I am under age 16.  The research I did says that if a parent isn't able to come in person to the passport office, then they need to fill out Form DS-3053 and have it notarized.  But what if neither parent can come in person?  Can I get a copy of that form signed and notarized by each parent and bring them both to the office?

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange!

Answer (score 25):

At the [US Department of State website for passports](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/under-16.html), it states that if parents are unable to appear:

> A third party may apply for the child's passport with a notarized
>   statement from both parents/guardians giving that third party
>   permission to apply for the child.
>
> The statement must include a photocopy of the parents/guardians'
>   identification.  When the statement is from only one parent/guardian,
>   the third party must present evidence of sole custody of the
>   consenting parent/guardian.

In all circumstances, you must be accompanied by one adult, but it doesn't have to be your parents.

Comment: It seems amazing that in the 21st century you still need to physically go somewhere to get a passport, but I guess the US will catch up with the rest of the world eventually.

Comment: Are there any countries that give passports without a physical visit? I know that I can renew mine online, but I still have to go to get the nationality card (which allows me to do the online passport thing).

Comment: I didn't have to visit the passport office in the UK when I got my first one ~15 years ago, and haven't had to since.

Comment: @patstew In the US a visit to a passport office isn't required, just a post office or something similar.

Comment: OK, any office. You do have to get the photo authenticated by someone trustworthy who isn't a family member, e.g. a doctor, though.

Comment: The system @patstew describes, authenticated photo but no office visit, was in effect when I got my first UK passport, in 1966.

Comment: @patstew At the moment a doctor (i.e. a GP) is one class of "recognised profession" not typically accepted to  countersign a passport photo in the UK. Too much time was being wasted on non-medical appointments. https://www.gov.uk/countersigning-passport-applications/accepted-occupations-for-countersignatories